# SQL Full backup job is taking too long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups

I am facing a strange issue with SQL Server 2012(Standard) Full backup job for the last 2 days.

Our database size is 1.3 TB and we are taking backups on a daily bases for all databases. From last 2 days without any error backups not happening. But I got job email alert with success in 13 sec.

I have checked on SQL server Full backup is running for last 10 hours.
Please suggest me for further.

I have searched in the error log and event viewer but I haven't found any error related to this backup job. And also I haven't found anything from job history as well it was showing last success history.

Comment: You should check sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks for backup session_id and find out for what it's waiting for

Comment: Yesterday i have check there is no wait tasks at that time. Only backup is running continuously.

Comment: What is reported as last_wait_type in sys.dm_exec_requests for this session?

Comment: Sorry i have not checked last wait_type.

Comment: Today i have created new maintenance plan for SQL backup it is running now. Last maintenance plan was running bit with in 3 sec it gives successful email alert.

Comment: Hi, again we are facing same issue like backup taking too long time to execute. Now the last_wait_type is ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION. And Status is showing suspended. Please suggest for this.

Comment: I am facing issue with 1.3 TB database only before it was running successfully with in 4:30 hours. Is something change from this database??

Comment: ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION indicates IO waits, maybe your disk have a problem?

Comment: Can you please let me know which type of disk problem it is??

Comment: If it is a disk problem how the other backups are running successfully?

Comment: @HARIVARMA, this question is not related to programming. I suggest you post DBA questions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).